# How to properly setup npm dependencies for local typescript development of two related packages

Tags: typescript, npm, rxjs

I'm developing two packages. One defines an interface and the other implements it. Both require a common package (rxjs).

As I'm co-developing both packages, I want to use the interface package from the local directory, using npm link,

```
implementation-package
   |- interface-package-> link to inteface-package
   |- rxjs

interface-package
   |-rxjs
```

However, this caused me some [well known issues with the Observable](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1744).

I tried to define the rxjs package as a peer dependency in the interface module:

```
implementation-package
   |- interface-package -> link to interface package
   |- rxjs

interface-package
```

However, now I'm having problems compiling the inteface package, because the missing dependency.

```
implementation-package> tsc 
interface-package/interface.ts(1,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/Rx'.
```

I also tried installing the interface package into the implementation package from the interface package's folder, but the result is the same.

The concrete question is, how do I setup such case to prevent duplicated references? May this have something to do with the typescript more than npm?

Comment: Create another package - for development purposes - that includes your two packages as dependencies and link them there. And your packages should have rxjs as peer dependencies.

Comment: @cartant I don't see how this will solve the issue, as I will have the same issue at the new package. Maybe the issue is more related to how typescript compiler solves dependencies?